# Is or Are to prefix boolean values

Tags: coding-style

When naming a boolean, or a function returning a boolean it's usual to prefix with 'is' e.g.

- isPointerNull
- isShapeSquare

What about when refering to multiple items, should it be:

- arePointersNull or isPointersNull
- areShapesNull or isShapesNull

I can see arguments for both; is offers consistency and perhaps slightly better readability, are makes the code read in a more natural way.

Any opinions?

Comment: "Whenever you can, please avoid inherent negatives" That's a really good point, I hadn't really thought about it that way before, but I'll remember that in future. Cheers!

Comment: Don't forget boolean methods that get called *after* some action might possibly change their referred-to values, e.g., `wasItemNull()` (as in JDBC).

Comment: A plural name like `isPointersNull` can be replaced with a singular group name like `isPointerSetNull`.

Comment: Pretty close [java-boolean-getters-is-vs-are](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12960554/java-boolean-getters-is-vs-are)

Comment: SensioLabsInsight has a code style check called _Boolean property should not be prefixed by "is"_. Does anyone know why that is?

Comment: OK, found the actual reason that it was complaining about:
"Boolean property accessor should not be setIsXXX nor getIsXXX but setXXX and isXXX"

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Firstly, `isPointersNull` is just ugly. Don't do that.

I typically go with `any` or `all`, as `are` can be ambiguous. Does it mean "there are null pointers" or "the pointers are all null"? `anyPointersNull` and `allPointersNull` clear that up, IMO.

Answer (score 13):

Please don't use isPointersNull. Consistency is no reason to sacrifice on grammar and readability.

Comment: +1 - I agree arePointersNull is better. You could also have PointersAreNull then an If statement clarity would be even better.

Comment: Yes it are!.....

Answer (score 4):

It depends on the language. If you are using Java, 'isPointersNull' will be interpreted as the 'pointersNull' field where 'arePointersNull' will not if you are using any JavaBean processing tools.

I agree that readability is paramount but bean conventions allow common parsing of objects.

Comment: well put chris.  even though a method name may not make sense to us a lot of tools expect you to stick to standard conventions like JavaBean syntax and you'll trip yourself up if you stray....only to end up conforming to the standard in the end.

Answer (score 3):

isPointersNull looks like a typo. arePointersNull communicates nicely the fact that more than a single object is involved in the consideration of this boolean. But if you want consistency you could refer to an array or collection, which your Pointers ought to be:

- isPointerArrayNull
- isPointerCollectionEmpty
- etc.

Comment: While does it communicate nicely that we're talking about multiple items, does it mean that *more than one is null* (and some may be non-null), or does it mean that *there is more than one pointer, and they're all null*?

Answer (score 2):

IMO - depends on the context (usage & readability) of the boolean variable.

For example:
- if the variable is referring to a single pointer being null, I would use: isPointerNull
- if the variable is referring to multiple pointers being null, I would use: arePointersNull

HTH.

Answer (score 2):

Really, really late to the show, but a few humble thoughts on one of the most misunderstood prefixing strategies:

- Code should give instructions, not ask questions. isUserAdmin? Are you asking me? I don't know, you tell me. Oh, is someone behind me? I'm not reading a Dostoevsky's story full of philosophical questions. I'm reading a formal set of commands for a computer to execute. Verbs in imperative mood, positive statements, logical conditions.
- Code should more or less be in grammatically correct English. Quantifiability and  plurality matter.

So

```
if (pointersAreNull())
```

or, as argued in the accepted answer, even less ambiguous

```
if (allPointersAreNull())
```

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

I personally go with isWhatever if I am referencing the getter method of a boolean variable no matter how ugly it is according go grammar rules.  But if I had a method that did some sort of checking of an object based on some businessy-rule (like if a number or numbers is/are prime) I would use names that would make my English teachers happy.