# Java boolean getters "is" vs "are"

Tags: java, naming-conventions, boolean

I know that the convention in Java for boolean getters is include the prefix "is".

```
isEnabled
isStoreOpen
```

But what if the subject is plural? That is, what if instead of wanting to know if a store is open, I wanted to know if all the stores are open?

`isStoresOpen()` doesn't make sense in English.

I'm tempted to write getters like:

```
areStoresOpen
areDogsCute
areCatsFuzzy
```

And I think that would make sense, but I've been told by others that I should just suck it up and abandon subject verb agreement and use `isStoresOpen`, `isDogsCute`, `isCatsFuzzy`.

Anyway, what should I do for boolean getters which operate on a plural subject?

Comment: I never see before a `are*()` getter.

Comment: Nice question, but I don't think it belongs here.

Comment: I always write `are*()` getters if they're grammatically correct.

Comment: If your object is a bean, I think you have to stick to either `is` or `has`...

Comment: if you are using are*() getter then it should return boolean[] in most cases, i think.

Comment: Very good question. Wondered this myself, quite a bit. As a lot of the answers have already pointed out, most frameworks, IDEs, and anything relying on a convention that I've encountered use the "get" / "set" / "is" pattern. Even if this is not a concern in your application, I would follow that convention regardless - your code will be far easier to follow (even by you) if you maintain a consistent naming convention (even if it doesn't sound grammatically odd at times).

Comment: It's true and I think in the end your right. It just seems wrong that I'm writing my code for the IDE's. Their goal is to make things easier for me but I end up having to bend my code to fit their expectations.

Comment: Honestly even isStoreOpen returning true/false doesn't sound right. If you say isStoreOpen then it's a question and you'd want to say yes or no, whereas you'd say true or false to a statement, which should look more like "storeIsOpen"... not that I advocate using that, it's definitely awkward

Comment: For me common sense wins with the convention. Just be consistent.

Comment: 'hasOpenStores()'? Only logical if you compose your objects. I've never needed 'areX()' to be gramatically correct.

Comment: Often it is not too hard to rephrase things so that a plural "all" becomes a singular "any" with a negated result (e.g. De Morgan's laws). `areAllStoresClosed()` --> `isAnyStoreOpen()` or `areAllStoresOpen()` --> `isAnyStoreClosed()`

Answer (score 154, accepted):

How about having decent enough english and following Java standard:

- `**are**StoresOpen()` > to be >> `isEveryStoreOpen()`
- `**are**CatsCute()` > to be >> `isEachCatCute()`

When in doubt of the right word I always like to hit up the thesaurus.

Comment: +1, this clearly conveys whether the returned value means isEveryStoreOpen() or isAnyStoreOpen() unlike the ambiguous isStoresOpen().

Comment: +1 This should be the accepted answer! Makes sense grammatically while keeping the Java `boolean`s `is` prefix convention. Plus, it provides a little bit of extra info that will be *really* useful for those non-native English speakers that happen to be maintainers of the codebase.

Comment: This answer changed my life! And it should be the accepted answer.

Comment: Yeah, but how do you phrase a variable name that conveys the following: "Are SOME [not all] stores open"?

Comment: How about `isAnyCatCute()` or `isAtLeastOneCatCute()`?

Comment: Thanks. How'd you phrase a sentiment to the effect of "isAtleastTwoCats," only with proper grammar?

Comment: @MichaelP. If this is something you are requiring in your codebase, then I would say you need to relook at the design of your classes. Your methods may well be expected to tell that there are no stores open, all stores open, is any store open, but if your require is strange enough that it warrants a relook at the design.
You  can write a method `getCountOfOpenStores()` and use the number in the logic directly. As a class exposing methods to others, this would be my choice rather than  a method that checks if 2 stores are open.
PS: This is all only from a practical implementation viewpoint.

Answer (score 67):

I can't remember which book this was from, but the essence is that code will be read many more times than it's written.  Write for readability.

Comment: Clean Code - Robert Martin

Comment: John B:  I haven't read that book; maybe I read a reference to it.  Another book for my list, though. :)

Comment: But be very careful you don't go too far.  `storesAreOpen()` would likely be the most grammatical (because of `if(storesAreOpen())`), but the boolean part of the name is now hidden in the middle of the method name, which breaks Java conventions _and_ readable code.

Comment: @nalply It means being able to understand the intent of the code after being away from it for six months. It means not making it difficult for someone else to understand the code. (Note: I wasn't necessarily taking a stand on `is` or `are` here.)

Comment: He answers the question in a very general way. It's true he doesn't address the specifics, but this is an answer. It may seem trite, but there is value to it (at least 24 people think so).

Comment: in order to clarify the answer I would add remark that **areStoresOpen()** is a good choice here.

Answer (score 38):

The convention is to prefix the getter-method with "is" not the variale itself.

e.g.

```
private boolean enabled;

public boolean isEnabled() {
    return enabled;
}
```

and

```
private boolean storesOpen;

public boolean isStoresOpen() {
    return storesOpen;
}
```

---

> isStoresOpen() doesn't make sense in English.

It might not make sense grammatically, but it follows the convention and looks readable enough.

Comment: Your answer makes sense, and I appreciate it. I think from an authoritative right/wrong position, you're right. I just don't want a convention that was intended to help us by being obvious, clear and easy to understand to abandon that purpose for the sake of adhering to its rules. But you're right - this is how it is, and that's what I asked about.

Comment: @kodai: I think it should not be considered as rule, but just a convention. But I believe while, writing code not following the convention, if it is not required, to make the code readable is the way to go.

Answer (score 19):

The Java Bean specification says to use `get` for getters unless it's a `boolean` then use `is`. `are` is non-standard and will not be recognized by anything that expects standard Bean naming.

Answer (score 18):

Lots of tools expect `is` or `get` and won't likely recognize `are`.

Try rephrasing them, like `getDogsAreFuzzy()` or `getStoresAreOpen()` or things like that for better compatibility and conventions.

Comment: Yes. Tools like bean utilities count on the word **is** to find boolean getters.

Answer (score 7):

## What do you code, **English** or **Java**?

When I read Java code, I expect things to be structural. Boolean methods starting with `is` is a good structure.

```
return 0;
```

Answer (score 4):

**-** `isEnabled()` can also be written as `getEnabled()` in `Java naming conventions`.

**-** Its just a good habit to follow the naming conventions, help when you are working with `Java Beans`.

Answer (score 3):

In general I think code should be as easily readable as possible so that a method can almost be read as a paragraph (as espoused by `Clean Code`). Therefore, I would name the method to sound / read as easily as possible and go with the grammer rule of `are`. With modern IDEs it is easy to find methods without looking specifically for `get` / `is`.

However, Kumar makes a good point about beans. A lot of tools will only look for `get` / `is`. In that case I might consider having both methods. One for ease of reading and one for tool use.

Answer (score 3):

In your question you're explicitly asking about getters. A getter returns some information about one instance of your class. For example you have a class `Store`. Now, `isStoreOpen` is a perfectly fine method name for a getter.

Next, you mention a method that checks if all stores are open. This method isn't a getter at all, because it doesn't return information about one instance but for all. Of course unless there is a class `Stores`. If this is the case, you should rethink your design, because Java already has ways to store a number of instances, e.g. arrays or collections, so you don't have to write extra classes.

If this is not the case, then this method name is perfectly fine. An alternative may be just `allStoresOpen` without the 'is'.

TL;DR: If you're dealing with multiple instances, it's not a getter. If it is, your design is bad.

Answer (score 2):

Quite honestly I would say definitely forget about the `are*` and stick with `is*`. Think of the `"is"` as the variable meaning and make a better name if possible.

I would say is isStoresOpen doesn't sound that bad, but you can make isStoresAreOpen if that sounds better for you.

But my general idea would be to stick to the conventions. Which is using "get" for getters and "is" for boolean types. Personally I think using "is" is sometimes already problematic. Yes - it does look good in "if" conditions, but sometimes I just write "get" when coding and check the drop down list for my needed variable and start wondering what's wrong and why I can't find it, then I realize it starts with "is"...

Answer (score 2):

**isStoresOpen()** in this StoresOpen is seems like a plural,

When you follow that Java Naming Convention and Java Beans Standards, they have predefined prefix's for boolean and other type, so you should follow Java Beans Naming Convention.

Let's come to your point
When you see **storesOpen** as in an English prospective, yes it looks like plural.
Once again take deep observation into that word,

Here

**storesOpen** is plural according to English grammar,

The out come of the **isStoresOpen** is not plural, instead of it is singular or you can say it is scalar in terms of programming convention.

It's out come is boolean, just true or false

Not like your English plural statement **true's** or **false's**

Not an array of **true** or **false**, or not a collections of **true** or **false**

So, here we can say that, here we are concerned with value that is return from that boolean bean method, not the name given to the property of class to point real world entity.

One more important thing is, whenever such boolean properties are used in classes and those are used by predefined libraries in any framework, then framework with use prefix '**is**' for retrieving  boolean values,

why means it's not that much of smarter than you as you know English grammar like plural/singular, multiplexer etc...

Answer (score 1):

In object-oriented programming, this should rarely, if ever, occur since `Store` or `Cat` or what have you should be a separate class, with its own `isOpen()` or `isFuzzy()` method.  If you have a higher type, consider splitting down to the more atomic level that you're actually using.  In general, objects should not be plural at the lowest level.